# Crash at "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info ()" mean?

Tags: c++, linker, runtime

I get a crash when I try to run an application and it points to this line:
Crash at "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info ()"

This crash does not happen always but it happens sometimes. I am not using any dynamic libraries. Any idea what does this crash mean ? Could this be a memory corruption ?

The class layout looks something like this :-
Base has 2 derived classes Derived1 and Derived2 (and many other derived classes). But in this scenario we are interested only in Derived1 and Derived2.

Base has virtual functions f1() and f2(). These are NOT pure virtual functions and have a basic implementation but these are overridden at Derived1 and Derived2

In Derived2, I have a pointer to Derived1 object.

In a Derived2::f2() I call Derived1_ptr->f1(). That's when I get this crash.

Derived1 and Derived2 are in different libraries.

Answer (score 3):

> Crash at `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info ()`

The most likely cause: you are using a dangling pointer, and the `vtable` has been overwritten with garbage.

> This crash does not happen always but it happens sometimes.

Dangling pointer bugs are often like that.

You didn't say what platform you are on. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (available in recent versions of GCC and Clang) will likely point you straight at the bug.